# Are two definitions of differential function equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Definition 1:**

From https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/tangentplanes/differentiability.pdf or [Differentiability for a function of two variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266483/differentiability-for-a-function-of-two-variables?rq=1)

A function $f(x, y)$ is differentiable at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ if $f_x(x_0,y_0)$ and $f_y(x_0,y_0)$ exist and $\Delta f = f(x_0 +\Delta x, y_0 +\Delta  y) − f(x_0,y_0)$ can be written in the form  $$\Delta f=f_x(x_0,y_0)\Delta x+f_y(x_0,y_0)\Delta y+\epsilon_1\Delta  x+\epsilon_2\Delta y$$ where $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are functions of $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ such that 
$$\lim\limits_{(\Delta x,\Delta y)\to(0,0)}\epsilon_1=\lim\limits_{(\Delta x,\Delta y)\to(0,0)}\epsilon_2=0.$$

**Definition 2:**
From http://higheredbcs.wiley.com/legacy/college/hugheshallett/0471484822/theory/hh_focusontheory_sectioni.pdf

A function $f(x, y)$ is differentiable at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ if $f_x(x_0,y_0)$ and $f_y(x_0,y_0)$ exist and $\Delta f = f(x_0 +\Delta x, y_0 +\Delta  y) − f(x_0,y_0)$ can be written in the form  $$\Delta f=f_x(x_0,y_0)\Delta x+f_y(x_0,y_0)\Delta y+o(\sqrt{\Delta  x^2+\Delta y^2}).$$

I wonder whether two above definitions of differential function are equivalent. Any explain are highly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps reading [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747137/equivalence-of-definitions-of-multivariable-differentiability#comment1560942_747137) can help you.